# Allow user interactivity in secondary window while modal dialog is open

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, modal-dialog

I'm developing a WPF application for which I have several peripherals.  I'm writing a stub for one of these peripherals that opens a secondary window which mimics the interface of the peripheral.  This is mainly for development and QA automation purposes.

The problem I am experiencing is that my application generally opens a modal dialog whenever it's expecting user input through the peripheral, and that dialog is blocking access to the stub's window, which means no user input.

Is there a way to have the dialog grant access to the secondary (stub) window while still blocking the main window?  I've tried placing the second window on a separate UI thread, but it still is blocked.  I'm currently looking into multiple app domains, but my application generally interacts with the peripheral through events, and (from my reading) those won't be shared across domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried the same in WPF but in Windows Forms a modal dialogue only affects forms created on the same thread.  If you create your peripheral window on a separate thread then it won't be blocked by the modal dialogue.  It would make passing data between that window and those created on the UI thread a bit more tedious but certainly not impossible.

Comment: I finally got this working, but I had to use a ShowDialog() instead of just Show() on the second thread.  This way the second window stays open, keeping the thread alive until the window closes.  Dialogs from the main window seem to only block windows on the thread shared by that dialog.  Finally, we already have a robust framework for handling events across multiple threads, so that wasn't an issue.